# Custom Terraform provider out of sync on Terraform Registry

Tags: terraform, provider, terraform-provider, terraform-registry

I am facing some issues with the synchronization of my new Terraform provider.

I created a Terraform provider (available at https://github.com/just1not2/terraform-provider-haproxy) and I started publishing it on the Terraform registry (available at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/just1not2/haproxy/latest). I used gorelease locally to generate the release/tag.

However, I had to amend some commits and delete the release/tag. Because my provider was not updating on Terraform, I found at the bottom of the page https://www.terraform.io/registry/providers/publishing that I probably needed to remove the webhook on Github and then click on the "Resync" button. However, when I click on it, the provider is not updated on the registry and the webhook is not created again. Now I can't possibly update my Terraform provider on the public registry !

Do you have any idea on how to solve this? Do you have any webhook Terraform registry content so I may try to create again the webhook manually?

**Note:** I already contacted the Terraform support but they did not reply to me!

Comment: I've been having the exact same issue lately and I too have not heard back from their support team. In fact they have ben utterly useless in providing any support. If you have made any progress with this I'd be very keen to know what you have done.